Stake transaction is showing inconsistent behaviour?
If anyone of you could help me, in what is wrong here.
I am not using sendAndConfirmTransaction() because of project requirements.
Using @solana/web3.js.
const stakeAccount = Keypair.generate();
  const rentExemptionAmount = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(StakeProgram.space);


  const amountToStake = (chainConfig.AMOUNT * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL) + rentExemptionAmount;

  const createAccountTransaction = StakeProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    stakePubkey: stakeAccount.publicKey,
    authorized: {
      staker: fromKeypair.publicKey,
      withdrawer: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    },
    lamports: amountToStake,
  });

  const transaction = new Transaction();
  transaction.add(createAccountTransaction);

  const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
  transaction.feePayer = fromKeypair.publicKey;

  transaction.sign(fromKeypair, stakeAccount);

  console.log("Sending create account transaction...");

  const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
  const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
    skipPreflight: false,
    preflightCommitment: "confirmed",
  });
  console.log("Create account transaction sent with signature:", signature);

  let status = null;
  while (status === null || status.confirmationStatus !== 'confirmed') {
    const response = await connection.getSignatureStatus(signature);
    status = response.value;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }

  console.log("Transaction confirmed");

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

  const delegateTransaction = StakeProgram.delegate({
    stakePubkey: stakeAccount.publicKey,
    authorizedPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    votePubkey: new PublicKey(chainConfig.VALIDATOR_ADDRESS),
  });
  console.log("here 5");

  console.log("delegatetxn here:", delegateTransaction);

  const delegateTx = new Transaction();
  delegateTx.add(delegateTransaction);

  const { blockhash: delegateBlockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  delegateTx.recentBlockhash = delegateBlockhash;
  delegateTx.feePayer = fromKeypair.publicKey;

  delegateTx.sign(fromKeypair);

  console.log("Sending delegate transaction...");

  const rawDelegateTransaction = delegateTx.serialize();
  const delegateSignature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawDelegateTransaction, {
    skipPreflight: false,
    preflightCommitment: "confirmed",
  });

  status = null;
  while (status === null || status.confirmationStatus !== 'confirmed') {
    const response = await connection.getSignatureStatus(delegateSignature);
    status = response.value;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); 
  }

  console.log("Delegate transaction sent with signature:", delegateSignature);

  let result = { transactionHash: delegateSignature };

  console.log("After result:", result, delegateSignature);

  return result.transactionHash;



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am looking for confirmation method i am using and its related code i wrote here , is the method correct or are there any better method, i know sendAndConfirmTransaction handles it internally but can't use it for my case,
